# How to ensure entity properties set against Jira issues are up to date if app.js dies and has to be restarted

Tags: jira, jira-rest-api, atlassian-plugin-sdk

I have a Jira Cloud Add On that listens for webhook events 'issuelink_created', 'issuelink_deleted' and 'connect_addon_enabled'.

When 'issuelink_created' or 'issuelink_deleted' events are received I update the entity properties for each issue to store key/values representing the current state of the links.

When 'connect_addon_enabled' is received I update the entity properties for all issues in Jira to store key/values representing the current state of the links.

All of the above works great.

My question.  If app.js which hosts the add on microservice goes down and has to be restarted, how do I update all entity properties for all issues in Jira?  Is there a best practice design approach like an event to listen for?  A hook I should create within app.js back to my index.js routes?  Also curious how to handle this for each tenant stored in my store.db with sqlite.

Appreciate any insight.

Comment: Very interesting question IMHO.We are just setting up our CI solution at work, and are using JIRA in the cloud. What is your motivation behind this 'current state of the links' project?

Comment: Our ultimate goal is to be able to search for issues in Jira having a specific link type.  So for example let's say I want to see all stories and tasks that do not have a link of type "Tested By".  That would immediately tell me our test case coverage.  My tool is basically updating JQL so you can search for those issues with a command like "hasIssueLinkType = 'Tested By'.  The tool is complete I just need a method to keep the Entity Properties for the issues in sync at all times so that queries are accurate.

Comment: Nice, Lovely idea. might end up doing the same thing on my end.